# Networkx and Matplotlib issue : self-loops are not printed

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, visualization, networkx

I have been trying to draw a networkx multidigraph with multiple self-loops on nodes using matplotlib for quite a few days now but nothing works.
After multiple tests, I narrowed the problem to Networkx with Matplotlib.
I executed the following tutorial https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/auto_examples/drawing/plot_selfloops.html
on my laptop and using an online python compiler but no self-loop get printed. I think there might be a bug somewhere since it is supposed to work according the official documentation.

Please do not propose to used Graphviz... I already did and it does not correspond to what I want.

Current Behavior
From the tutorial, here is the image that I obtain :
[image]
Expected Behavior
The image that I'm supposed to obtain :
[image]

My environment :
Python version: 3
NetworkX version: 2.5 (I upraded it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation page of `networkx` that the question links to is for the *latest* version of `networkx`, i.e., the development version, which has not yet been released.

Self-loops are mentioned in the module: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/d70b314b37168f0ea7c5b0d7f9ff61d73232747b/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L697-L704
on branch `main`.

Self-loops are not mentioned in the same module on branch `v2.5`:
https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/36383ccc94a2e2d50893e13bb2a3ec96e5f6518f/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py

So it appears that plotting self-loops using `matplotlib` has been added for release in `networkx >= 2.6`. The latest stable release, [`networkx == 2.5.1`](https://pypi.org/project/networkx/2.5.1/) gives the same result that the question shows (i.e., no self-loops present).

Indeed, the `networkx` documentation page linked from the question is an example, whose file was added after `networkx == 2.5` was released (and before `networkx == 2.5.1` was released, though the latter seems to have originated from another branch than `main`): https://github.com/networkx/networkx/commit/6108e42fa70fec2d1af0f177bf5518d6b60981d6#diff-27445a1ef749e821a838e843aee62f8fbde8c0cfdfde0717c73eb3355f8d7a77
The relevant pull request is:
https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/4430

This example does not exist in the stable version's documentation: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/index.html#drawing

---

To draw self-loops with `networkx`, please install a development version. One way to do this is to clone the repository https://github.com/networkx/networkx using `git`, and then follow the installation instructions at:
https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/INSTALL.rst#install-the-development-version

Instead of cloning, downloading is possible too, using the "Code" button on the main page of the GitHub repository of `networkx` (near the "About" description), or by directly downloading from a URL like: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/archive/refs/heads/main.zip (from a browser, or using another program, e.g., cURL).

Answer (score 0):

The example you link mentions 2.6 in a comment

> As of version 2.6, self-loops are drawn by default with the same styling as other edges

I checked what happens with the development version and I get the correct plot, so this looks like it is perhaps a new feature. If you need it now then you'll probably have to install the dev version from GitHub. Example plots are below.

#### 2.5.1

[image]

#### 2.6rc1.dev0

[image]